# Optical flow based vehicle detection and tracking MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, tracking, matlab-cvst, opticalflow

I am working on Optical flow based vehicle detection and tracking purely on MATLAB.
Provided that camera is in motion and object is also in motion.

Previously, a lot work is done on camera in stationary condition and object moving. Optical flow vectors can easily be determined using LUCAS-KANADE method and Horn and shunck. Sipmly taking two consecutive images results are achevied. I have done tests and acheived.

There is also simulink example viptrafficof_win available.

I need to perform optical flow based detection and tracking for camera and object both in motion. What methodology shall I pursue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your camera is moving, you would have to separate the camera motion (ego motion) from the motion of the objects. There are different ways of doing that.  Here is a [recent paper](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/~narayana/MotionSegmentationICCV2013.pdf) describing an approach using the orientations of optical flow vectors.

Comment: Hi Dima,I need to ask. Now that I have a detected object within bounding box. How can I track it in the next frame? Could you please tell me the best solution.

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html